# How to expedite switching between iFrames in Selenium Webdriver with Java code?

Tags: java, c#, selenium, iframe, selenium-webdriver

For Selenium WebDriver: I'm using Eclipse IDE and Java code

Application under testing: Built in C#

My script needs to switch between frames and perform some actions. This needs to be done quite frequently. The problem is that script execution gets very slow (around 20 seconds delay) whenever switching statements are executed. The frame hierarchy is as follows:

1 parent frame: MainFrame
3 child frames: left, center and right

The set of statements for any one switch looks something like:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame("mainFrame"); //switching to parent frame. This statement causes the delay
driver.switchTo().frame("left"); //switching to left frame
```

Please suggest if there is a way to avoid this delay.

Comment: You are using a Java app built using C#? What does that mean? Your code looks like Java to me. Your code looks fine to me, how do you know it's the frame switch that is taking 20s?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out Jeff. I've updated the title and added more details to make the information clear. You're right, I'm using Java code.
I had some idea which method might be causing delay and I narrowed it down to a statement using debug and breakpoints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store a frame as an element variable first and then switch to it.

Here is an example:

```
var frameExample = driver.FindElement(By.className("myFrame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frameExample);
```

So essentially, you store frames in element variables and switch when needed, it will help with performance issues.

Comment: Thanks Mystia! It worked like a charm. All that delay is gone. Just like that. :)

Comment: On C# I'm getting `frameElement cannot be converted to IWebElementReference`